# ConstraintLayout content stuck in middle of screen

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

After adding a `ConstraintLayout` inside a `ScrollView`, I noticed that the content remains stuck in the middle of the screen (both horizontally and vertically). I already tried add `android:layout_gravity="top"` to the main `ConstraintLayout` but that didn't work. Is there something else I can use to position the content at the top?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cl_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:contentPadding="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_disclaimer">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_disclaimer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cv_title"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cv_description"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:contentPadding="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_disclaimer"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/cl_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_allergies"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ll_ingredients">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_allergies"
                        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_allergies"
                        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_allergyinfo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_allergies"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ll_ingredients">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_allergyinfo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_ingredients"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_allergyinfo"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_ingredients"
                        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_ingredients"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Current result**

[image]

Comment: not sure what the problem is. Is it that there's black empty space all around the views? Maybe it's just the padding you define on your constraint layout; what are the values there?

Comment: Also have you tried adding app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" to the outer constraint layout?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Yes but no difference. I didn't know constraints neeeded to be added to the `ConstraintLayout` itself. There's also problems with the margins because if the content is bigger than the screen, then the margins work perfectly but yet it's the opposite if the content isn't.

Comment: They're not always needed, it depends on what you want to do. Do you want the dialog with the list of allergies to appear at the top of the screen?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo they're not dialogs, they are CardViews. The attached screenshots is how I want them laid out. Those margins are temperamental.

Comment: I see the CardViews; I said dialogs in the broader sense and not as in Android Dialog. But somehow I'm missing the problem still. When you say "the content remains stuck in the middle of the screen" do you mean that you simply cannot scroll it even though it's inside a scrollview?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo The content should be further up on screen. The 'disclaimer' `Textview` has a margin underneath it when it shouldn't, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two important things are going on here.

The first is that your `ScrollView` specifies `android:fillViewport="true"`. This means that whenever the contents of the ScrollView are "smaller" than the screen size, they will be stretched to fill the screen. In other words, your `wrap_content` ConstraintLayout will only actually *wrap its content* when you have to scroll. In all other cases, your ConstraintLayout will functionally be `match_parent` in height.

The second is that the constraints on your CardView, TextView, and second CardView form a vertical *chain*. Chains have special behavior regarding spacing when the parent is larger than the sum of the views in the chain (which it is due to the `fillViewport` behavior discussed above); the default is "spread", which will position the three views such that all the remaining space is evenly divided into four chunks (one at the start of the chain, one between the first two views, one between the second two views, and the last at the end of the chain).

How to fix it, though?

The best thing to do is to **break the chain**. Assuming you just want the views all stacked one after the other, starting from the top of the screen, there's no need to use a chain. To break the chain, **remove the bottom constraint** from each view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    ...>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        ...>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_title"
            ...
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

            ...

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_disclaimer"
            ...
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cv_title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_description"
            ...
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_disclaimer"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

            ...

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Alternatively, you could delete the `fillViewport` attribute from your ScrollView. Without this, the child ConstraintLayout won't ever be stretched to fill the screen, and `wrap_content` will mean that there's never any extra space to spread out between your chain views.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` from your *ll_allergies* `LinearLayout`. When copied on my AS it was this line that was adding the unnecessary space between the textview and the layout. Alternatively, keep the constraint and add 0dp on its height so that it enforces the constraint.

UPDATE after comment: I think your views are overlapping because the bottom constraint of ll_allergies is on the top of ll_ingredients instead of ll_allergyinfo. Try changing this:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ll_ingredients"
```

to this:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ll_allergyinfo"
```

and bring back the wrap_content of ll_alergies. Hopefully, now everything will fall into place

Comment: Neither of those work for me. The first suggestion makes the `LinearLayout` disappear, and the second suggestion causes the other `CardView` items to overlap each other.

Comment: @MacaronLover Does the latter remove the unwanted space at least? In my case it does. If so, we can see why the overlap happens and correct that as well.

Comment: Yes, it does surprisingly

Comment: @MacaronLover it doesn't surprise me because if you want the layout to match the constraint that's what you generally do. If you set wrap_content instead it respects that first and doesn't always match the constraint. So which of the views are overlapping, so I can have a look. Could you post the ids in particular, please?

Comment: I made a mistake. Nothing overlaps, just the `LinearLayout` (ll_allergies) is now gone

Comment: Fixed, but the margins issue still remains

Comment: @MacaronLover What's wrong exactly with the margins? and what views are affected specifically? Is it the fact that within that cardview the text and images are not aligned? It would help to know exactly how you want it to appear

Comment: The problem is the 'disclaimer' TextView (tv_disclaimer). I added `android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"` to it, but it looks a lot bigger during runtime.

Answer (score -1):

**Update**: *response no longer valide after the code was updated*

There are some errors in your code:

1.you set the layout to be to bottom of itself

```
android:id="@+id/ll_ingredients"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_ingredients"`
```

2. the id  "*ll_alighting*" is not defined

Comment: Those were just typos. Even with these corrections, the problem still exists